# Extract or Group by End of Year in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Using this date range 02/03/2014 - 03/20/2016 how to generate this kind of result using sql

> 02/03/2014 - 12/31/2014
>
> 01/01/2015 - 12/31/2015
>
> 01/01/2016 - 03/20/2016

Comment: What have you tried so far and what hasn't worked for you? My way of dealing with this would be to link to a date table and then do a group by the year and max the date

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to know what's wrong with you

Comment: @user1852837 You could try answering the questions that have been asked of you already before asking for examples.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by building a recursive CTE.

**Query**

```
declare @startdate as date = '01/01/2014';
declare @enddate as date = '03/20/2016';

with dates as(  
    select dt = dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, @startdate) + 1, -1)
    where dateadd(yy, 1, @startDate) <= @endDate
    union all
    select dateadd(yy, 1, dt)
    from dates
    where dateadd(yy, 1, dt) <= @endDate
)
select cast(dt as date) as dt
from dates
union
select @enddate;
```

###[`Find a working demo here`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485160/last-day-of-year-two-dates)###

Comment: is that possible to make like this 01/01/2014 - 12/31/2014, 01/01/2015/ - 12/31/2015, 01/01/2016 - 03/20/2016?

Comment: if the range start like this 02/02/2014 - 03/20/2016 it should be break apart to 02/02/2014 - 12/31/2014, 01/01/2015 - 12/31/2015, 01/01/2016 - 03/20/2016? is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(date_column) MaxDateYearWise,datepart(YYYY,date_column) Year 
into #dt 
from date_range_table
group by datepart(YYYY,date_column)


select MaxDateYearWise from #dt

drop table #dt
```

--- Above query might give you the required result.